# I have written this code but when I try to execute it shows segmentation fault core dumpe

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void main(){
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen("test","r");

        if(fp=NULL){
                printf("Error in opening file\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        else{
                char str[15],arr[200],temp,*add;
                add=arr;
                int i;

                while(!feof(fp)){
                        fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
                        for(i=0;i<(strlen(str)/2)+1;i++){
                                temp=str[i];
                                str[i]=str[strlen(str)-(i+1)];
                                str[strlen(str)-(i+1)]=temp;
                        };
                        strcpy(add,str);
                        add+=(strlen(add)+1);
                        *(add-1)=' ';
                };
                *(arr+strlen(arr))='\0';
                printf("%s \n",arr);
        };
        fclose(fp);
}
```

This code is written to read text from a file named test that contains only words and spaces and multiple lines.Whenever I try to execute it shows segmentation fault.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see where the code breaks?

Comment: Formatting and indentation is not important for the compiler, but it is for people reading your code. Please try to format and indent it nicely so it's easier for us to read and understand.

Comment: I also recommend you read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Lastly a hint: If the string in `arr` is not terminated when you do `*(arr+strlen(arr))='\0'`, what do you think the call to `strlen(arr)` will do?

Comment: fp will always be null because of `fp = NULL`, It should be `if (fp == NULL)`. From there on fp is stdin.

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function.  (regardless of what visual studio might allow) they both have a return type of `int`, I.E.  `void` is an error

Comment: regarding: ` printf("Error in opening file\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error is from a system function (other than any of the `scanf()` family) then should call `perror()` as that outputs the enclosed text and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: regarding: `fscanf(fp,"%s",str);`  When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  When using the input format specifier '%s' or '%[...]', always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer. because a) those input format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input and b) to avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow, which would be undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line. 2) insert appropriate space inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators  3) use meaningful variable (and parameter) names.  Names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)

Comment: regarding: `while(!feof(fp)){
                        fscanf(fp,"%s",str);`  the function: `feof()` does not do what the code is expecting it to do.  Suggest replacing these two lines with; `while( 1 == fscanf( fp, "%14s", str )  )`

Comment: My Turbo C compiler from 1989 says "possibly incorrect assignment" when I compile this. Either you are using a compiler which is worse than Turbo C from 1989, you have have no warnings enabled.

Comment: @user3629249 No that advise is complete nonsense. What you refer to is the "yoda conditions" and they went obsolete in the year 1989, when compilers started to warn for "possibly incorrect assignment". Please don't recommend people to pick up a confused coding style from the early 80s. Use proper compilers instead.

Comment: @Lundin,  Exactly which 'advice' are you referring to as being 'obsolete'?

Comment: @user3629249 Placing the constant first, `while(1 == fscanf(...)`. This is the "yoda conditions", which is a very obsolete trick from the 1980s, that should neither be used nor recommended today.

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
if(fp=NULL){
```

Should be

```
if(fp==NULL){
```

`gcc` with `-Wall` option should have warn you about this.

I advice you to write `if (NULL == fp){...` that way, if `==` becomes a `=`, the compiler won't emit a warning, but an error telling you that you cannot change the `NULL` value...

Comment: Or `if(!fp) {...}` ??

Comment: Something nice to get in the habit of for developers in general is to put the constant first so that the compiler will generate an error, whether you are developing in C, C++ or Java. `if (null == fp)`.  If you had written `if (null = fp)`, this would have generated a compiler error in any language. Just to re-iterate what purplepsycho said.

Comment: @jiveturkey No that advise is complete nonsense. What you refer to is the "yoda conditions" and they went obsolete in the year 1989, when compilers started to warn for "possibly incorrect assignment". Please don't recommend people to pick up a confused coding style from the early 80s. Use proper compilers instead.

Comment: @Lundin,  if your speaking about placing the literal first in a comparison.  *I* have often seen, even with modern (latest version) compilers that no warning message is output when the literal is on the right.  There is nothing 'yoda' about 'defensive' coding practices.

Comment: @user3629249 The "yoda conditions" have been criticized since the 1980s since they obfuscate the code. Since the year 1989, they have little to do with defensive programming, since it's all about enabling compiler warnings. The gcc compiler warns for this even without `-Wall -Wextra`. So did Turbo C from 1989. There's no excuse for compilers not to warn for this in the year 2018. And it's also the programmer's responsibility to enable warnings and not use crap compilers, just as it is their responsibility not to use "clever" tricks that obfuscate the code.